# Mysql select values from table where not exist in other table

Tags: mysql, sql

I need an sql query to select a value from a table where it doesn't have a certain entry in another table. For example, considering the tables customers and customershop:

Customers

```
Id   Name
1    Steve
2    John
3    Bob
```

Customershop

```
CustomerId Item
1          Kiwi
1          Apple
2          Kiwi
2          Banana
3          Banana
3          Apple
```

I need a query for mysql so it can return Bob if looking for customers that don't have Kiwi in the customershop table. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: For a start you could have used the title of your question as a search expression...

Answer (score 2):

As your title of your question already says, use `NOT EXISTS` and a correlated subquery.

```
SELECT *
       FROM customers c
       WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                FROM customershop s
                                WHERE s.customerid = c.id
                                      AND s.item = 'Kiwi');
```